# Read .mp4 file from firebase storage using fs to send that video to tenserflow model

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, mp4, fs

my graduation project is to convert video into text.
I'm trying to read video uploaded in Firebase storage & sent from android app, to send it to TenserFlow model.
but I can't read the video.

#### here is my function:

```
exports.readVideo = functions.storage
.object()
.onFinalize(async (object) => {
    const bucket = admin.storage().bucket(object.bucket);
    const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), object.name);
    console.log(tempFilePath);
    console.log('download');
    // note download
    await bucket
        .file(object.name!)
        .download({
            destination: tempFilePath,
        })
        .then()
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log({
                type: 'download',
                err: err,
            });
        });
    console.log('read');
    // note read
    let stream = await bucket
        .file(object.name!)
        .createReadStream({
            start: 10000,
            end: 20000,
        })
        .on('error', function (err) {
            console.log('error 1');
            console.log({ error: err });
        })
         await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log('error 2');
            stream.on('finish', resolve);
            console.log('error 3');
            stream.on('error', reject);
            console.log("end!")
            stream.on('end', resolve);
        }).catch((error) => {
            // successMessage is whatever we passed in the resolve(...) function above.
            // It doesn't have to be a string, but if it is only a succeed message, it probably will be.
            console.log("oups! " + error)
        });

    console.log('tempFile size2', fs.statSync(tempFilePath).size);­­­

    return fs.unlinkSync(tempFilePath);
});
```

and I got that error:

> Function execution took 60008 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message shows, the regular file system on Cloud Functions is read only. The only place you can write to is `/tmp`, as also shown in the documentation on [file system access in Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#file_system). I'm not sure why `os.tmpdir()` doesn't give you a location at that path, but you might want to hard-code the directory.

One thing to keep in mind: `/tmp` is a RAM disk and not a physical disk, so your allocated memory will need to have enough space for the files you write to it.

Comment: thank you this helped me. I edit my code, now I have an error in the last promise while deploying the function.
Function execution took 60008 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'
do you have an idea what is this!!

Comment: That error typically indcates that you'e not handing all async operations correctly. See https://www.google.com/search?q=Function+execution+took+60008+ms%2C+finished+with+status%3A+%27timeout%27 for some previous occurrences (and fixes).